# Getting the error of Result set not closed and Invalid cursor state in the same code

Tags: java, database, swing, applet

we have done this code in java swing. We have a database table nodes and a copy of that table nodecopy. Our motive is to draw a line from a particular node to another destination. 
Here +tablename+ refer to the table which is getting created every time when got clicked on the screen(a node is also created when clicked).

This code showing error as `invalid cursor state` and `result state not closed`
Please guide

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{

   int stX,stY,endX,endY;
    try
    {

    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:router");
    Statement sta = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=sta.executeQuery("Select * from nodecopy;");

                String tablename;
                ResultSet rs1;

                while(rs.next())
                {
                    tablename=rs.getString("1");
                    tablename=tablename.trim();
                    System.out.println("select * from "+tablename+";");
                    try
                    {
                        rs1=sta.executeQuery("select * from "+tablename+";");
                        String name,val;

                        if(rs1.next())
                        {

                            name=rs1.getString(1);
                            val=rs1.getString(2);
                            System.out.println(name+":"+val);
                        }

                        a=search(node_name,tablename);
                        stX=node_x_coordinate[a];
                        stY=node_y_coordinate[a];

                        String dest=rs1.getString(1);
                        b=search(node_name,dest);

                        endX=node_x_coordinate[b];
                        endY=node_y_coordinate[b];

                        System.out.println(tablename+"\t"+dest+"\t"+stX+"\t"+stY+"\t"+endX+"\t"+endY);

                        Color clr=new Color((int)(Math.random()*999999999));
                        g.setColor(clr);
                        g.drawLine(stX,stY,endX,endY);

                        JLabel vall;
                        add(vall=new JLabel(rs1.getString(2).trim()));
                        vall.setForeground(clr);
                        vall.setBounds((stX+endX)/2,(stY+endY)/2,40,40);
                        System.out.println(tablename+"\t"+dest+"\t"+stX+"\t"+stY+"\t"+endX+"\t"+endY);


                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                           System.out.println(e);
                           sta.execute("delete from nodecopy where node='"+tablename+"';");
                           sta = con.createStatement();
                           rs=sta.executeQuery("Select * from nodecopy;");

                    }

                }//end of while
                sta.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
}
```

Comment: Please post the *actual* exceptions, stack traces, and messages. Not your paraphrases and approximations. For example, is it 'result set not closed' or 'result state not closed'? Or, more probably, 'result set closed'?

Comment: Sorry for that!! I was getting error as "result set not closed"

Answer (score 1):

1. The "Result state not closed" is probably caused by another exception in combination with your `sta.close()` statement which is not put into a `finally` block
2. No idea about the "invalid cursor state" exception. But probably easier to find if you would print out the whole stack trace (`e.printStackTrace()` instead of `System.out.println(e)`)
3. You really, really do not want to perform database queries in the `paint` method. It will block the Event Dispatch thread. You should perform the queries on a background thread, and make the necessary information available to your `JComponent`
4. You typically override `JComponent#paintComponent( Graphics )` and not the `JComponent#paint( Graphics )` method
5. When you override the `paintComponent` method, do not forget to call `super.paintComponent`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I will try to rectify my error using this points.

Answer (score 0):

In a finally block try to close all resultSet, statements, connection in this order.